# Pass Dynamic PHP variables to other PHP page via URL

Tags: php, variables, url

I think the question is clear from the heading.
I have a PHP file, call it PHP1. In that PHP1, I have a URL looking pretty much like

`www.mywebsite/script.php?color=red&sky=blue&past=gone`

Where I am confused is that the values 'red' and 'blue' and 'gone' are in three dynamic variables: `$var1`, `$var2` and `$var3`.

How can I post these variables through URL into a second PHP file, PHP2.

In the PHP2 file, I want to recieve the values like:

```
$var1 = $_GET['color'];
$var2 = $_GET['sky'];
$var3 = $_GET['past'];
```

How can I achieve this? I know I can use ajax and all, but URL is my only resort here.

Comment: Change `$_POST` with `$_GET` if you really have no other option than to use the URL (ps: do you know about cookies and sessions? That would be an alternative to get params)

Comment: you cant post with url you can just send the data to another page...

Comment: Okay, how can I do that by making use of $_GET? pls do provide me the the example URL and the receiving section.

Comment: Check my answer.Use it PHP2 file

Comment: Arif, Thanks for the time. But as I told, I cant use cookies or sessions here. Its a kinda in the midst of an ugly predicament. Okay, What if I can use $_GET? how to I pass variables? I mean variables like $var1. not values like red. how can I write the url passing variables?

Comment: @AshifShereef will the parameter be same as color , sky and past ?

Comment: yes. Parameter ill by color, sky and past

Comment: @Ashif Shereef, check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for how to generate dynamic url

in your php1 file

```
$c = "red";
$s = "blue";
$stat ="past";

//Now you need to generate a dynamic url in your php1 file

$url = 'www.mywebsite/script.php?color='.$c.'&sky='.$s.'&past='.$stat;
//now genearte a dynamic link
echo '<a href="'. $url.'">Click me</a>';
//you have dynamic link. after clicking it will take you to different page
//your url shoule be www.mywebsite/script.php?color=red&sky=blue&past=gone
//just concanate
```

Php2 file

```
echo 'color'.$_GET["color"].' SKY '.$_GET["sky"].' STAT '.$_GET["past"];
```

//it should work

Answer (score 0):

YOu can not get values passed with url from $_POST.

Try this:

```
$var1= $_GET['color'];
$var2 = $_GET['sky'];
$var3= $_GET['past'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `header('Location')` :

```
header('Location:/script.php?color=red&sky=blue&past=gone');
```

It will redirect the user to the second page.
You can then gather the values using `$_GET` superglobal

```
$var1= $_GET['color'];
$var2 = $_GET['sky'];
$var3= $_GET['past'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get values via url like that, you need to use `$_GET['']` for it. But using session is the best option for doing it. just rewrite your code like that -

```
session_start();
$SESSION['data1'] = 'red';
```

Then retrieve your data where you want.

Comment: As I said, My only resort is using a URL. Because I am doing this from inside of a custom function in a custom API which only gives me the URL method to pass data to another page.

Comment: Then you need to do it using $_GET['data']

Comment: Then How can I do with $_GET? I am sorry for the confusion caused. Pls provide me with an example URL and a receiving section.

Comment: If you want to receive it from script.php, then write $GET['color'], $GET['sky'] etc, then you can store it in any variable and can use it where you want.

Answer (score 0):

In **PHP**, we are using **HTTP** protocol. 
**HTTP** can do request/responses between client and server. 
Client is browser and server is in location of our url. 
You may use **GET** request or **POST**. 
**GET** parameters are:

- seen in url
- you can bookmark this page
- it would be in browser history
- it has length limit.
  The other type of communication is **POST** where:
- you dont see this in url
- you cannot bookmark this page
- it won't be in browser history
- it doesn't have length limit

You may use HTML form with specified method GET or POST to send request.

Answer (score 0):

I think `header` will be helpful

```
<?php
    $variable1 = "red";
    $variable2 = "blue";
    $variable3 = "gone";
    header("Location:/script.php?color=$variable1&sky=$variable2&past=$variable3");
?>
```

To receive the variable in another page use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`

```
<?php
    $var1 = $_GET['color'];
    $var2 = $_GET['sky'];
    $var3 = $_GET['past'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have dynamic parameters in URL use foreach statement like this

```
$temp = "var";
$param = "";
$i=1;
$url = "samplepage.php?";
foreach($_GET as $key=>$values)
{
$tmp = $temp."".$i;
$param = $key;
$$param = $key;

// it is assumed $var1, $var2 and $var3 is defined before processing url
echo $tmp." value is ".$$tmp."\n";
$url = $url."".$$param."=".$$tmp."&"; 
$i++;
}
$url = rtrim($url, "&");
header("Location: ".$url);
```

[`Demo`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f3f087566804946564c890cfc98c6fa2956a1905)

Url Might be anything in PHP1, it get and passes same parameter with same values to next page

Answer (score 0):

In PHP1:

```
$var1= $_POST['color'];
$var2 = $_POST['sky'];
$var3= $_POST['past'];
header("Location:/script.php?color={$var1}&sky={$var2}&past={$var3}");
```

In PHP2:

```
$var1= $_GET['color'];
$var2 = $_GET['sky'];
$var3= $_GET['past'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this get thethod:

```
$var1= $_GET['color'];
$var2 = $_GET['sky'];
$var3= $_GET['past'];
```

OR

```
$var1= $_REQUEST['color'];
$var2 = $_REQUEST['sky'];
$var3= $_REQUEST['past'];
```

Comment: This is url: www.mywebsite/script.php?color=red&sky=blue&past=gone

Comment: As I already told, what if the values, red, blue and gone are stored in $var1,$var2 and $var3. These are dynamic. how to send variables?

Comment: $url = sprintf("www.mywebsite/script.php?color=%s&sky=%s&past=%s",$var1,$var2,$var3);
echo $url; Do you want that?

Comment: You can use sprintf in PHP to pass variables through url. For example:$url = sprintf("www.mywebsite/script.php?color=%s&sky=%s&past=%s","red","blue","gone");